# Real time gps tracking google maps

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I'm building an application which has to show multiple vehicles on the map and update its current position on interval. I have managed to create and place the markers on the map, however I cannot figure out of how to update each markers position.

To update the position I'm using google built in setPoistion method, however I keep getting (setPosition is not a function error)

I get gps coordinates of the vehicles from external source, however if it helps, i have included a sample of the data.

```
var sampleData= [{"ObjectID":"001","Latitude":51.418611111111,"Longitude":-0.057166666666667},
            {"ObjectID":"002","Latitude":51.54175,"Longitude":-0.35825},
            {"ObjectID":"003","Latitude":51.544666666667,"Longitude":5.9852777777778}]; 


function initialize() {
$.post("../test/test.php", function(data){ 
    var markers = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    var myMarkers = new Array();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.505568, -0.118421);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

    // Add markers to array & add markers to the map
    for (index in markers){
        myMarkers[ markers[index]['ObjectID']] = addMarker(map, markers[index]);
    };

    // Update markers location
    setTimeout(function(){
        for(index in markers){
            setPositions(markers[index]['ObjectID']);
        }

    },10*1000);


    // Update markers position function
    function setPositions(data){
   // Im using default location as the vehicles are not moving at current state.
        data.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(51.505568, -0.118421));
    }

    function addMarker(map,data){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude,data.Longitude),
            map: map,
            title: data.ObjectID
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: data.ObjectID

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
            infowindow.open(map,marker); 
        });
    }

});
```

}

Comment: What is `markers[index]['ObjectID']`? You are supposed to call `setPosition` on a marker object.

Comment: Its the marker Object its self. If you would call alert(markers[index]['ObjectID']) in the loop, you would get 001,002,003.

Comment: 001,002,003 is not a marker object! Maybe a reference of yours to the marker object.

Comment: I apologies, it is a reference to the object. But can't I use reference to the object to call the object? and if not how could i possibly call each individual object within the loop, so the function could place the correct marker to the correct location?

Comment: What about `setPositions(markers[index]);` ?

Comment: it still returns "TypeError: data.setPosition is not a function"

Comment: It's difficult to say. You have sample data, an AJAX call, etc. We don't know how you affect your variables. Looks quite complicated to me how you did it. See http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/4hrtn/ for a simple example. Markers are first placed at their original position, then they are all moved to the center of the map.

Comment: Thanks that helped, but now I'm facing an issue of cross-referencing markers from the array to markers from the location source. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Here is how I'd do it: 1) AJAX call 2) For each result (see [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)) create a marker 3) Push each marker to a markers array 4) You now have an array of markers which you can use to loop through your markers.